# How can I update an element's styles dynamically in CodePen.io?

Tags: styles, codepen, setattribute

In Codepen, I created a div, and gave it some attributes:

```
  let lettersWritten = document.createElement("div");
  lettersWritten.setAttribute("class", "lettersWritten");
  lettersWritten.style.height = writtenHeight;
  lettersWritten.style.width = writtenWidth;
  lettersWritten.textContent = "<------ WRITTEN to date";
```

Codepen created the div, set the class, added the text, but did not update the height and width. Codepen.io does not update element.style with call to element.style.

How can I update an element's style?

Answer (score 0):

Codepen.io will update an element's style with a call to setAttribute:

```
  let lettersWritten = document.createElement("div");
  lettersWritten.setAttribute("class", "lettersWritten");
  lettersWritten.setAttribute("style", "height:"+writtenHeight+"px;width:"+writtenWidth+"px;");
  lettersWritten.textContent = "<------ WRITTEN to date";
```

Here's a link to the Codepen with fix and comments:
https://codepen.io/theship/pen/e615b372bd408f89f0cb94d4f7b16cb0